# Generate MAX for every column in a group bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have these relations:

```
a01x = FOREACH a01 GENERATE ndggr, 1 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8;
a02x = FOREACH a02 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 1 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a03x = FOREACH a03 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 1 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a04x = FOREACH a04 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 1 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a05x = FOREACH a05 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 1 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a06x = FOREACH a06 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 1 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a07x = FOREACH a07 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 1 AS c7, 0 AS c8; 
a08x = FOREACH a08 GENERATE ndggr, 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2, 0 AS c3, 0 AS c4, 0 AS c5, 0 AS c6, 0 AS c7, 1 AS c8; 

aunion = UNION a01x, a02x, a03x, a04x, a05x, a06x, a07x, a08x;
agroups = GROUP aunion BY ndggr;
```

and, considering ndggr is my key, I want to obtain a relation where every tuple is like

```
001, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
155, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
200, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

so for every group I want something like

```
ndggr, MAX(c1), MAX(c2),  ... , MAX(c8)
```

how can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading some basic Apache Pig documentation tbh.

```
maxes = foreach agroups {
   generate
     group as ndggr,
     MAX(agroups.c1) as c1_max,
     ...
     MAX(agroups.c8) as c8_max
  ;
};
```

Comment: It works indeed. Could not find a clear example. I'll peruse the docs next time. Thanks Alexey